# python for printing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is part of my Perl script. As you see, this script will print out  usage information about the script. The first `_EOF_` is a beginning mark of the printing information, The second `_EOF`  is a end mark of the printing information. And all the information will keep the same format as I typed.

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    'h|help'                => \$help,
) or usage();


usage() if $help;

sub usage {
        #$"=',';
        print STDERR <<_EOF_;

xmlcollect [-h] [-g]  [-d <spooldir>] [-m <pmpath>]  [-f <regex>] [-x] [-norbs] [-nornc] [-noenb] [-maxrop <num>] [-job <name>] [-subnet <subnetwork>]

Fetch XML files from a directory and store the file collection in a zip
file ready for collection.

Each time the tool is run, it will check all available files and only
include unfetched files in the output zip.  Only once instance of the 
collection
is permitted at any time.

-h       : Show help
-g       : Debug mode
-d       : Spool directory (default: $spooldir)
-m       : PM dirs to search on nodes, comma separated list (default: @pmpaths)
-f       : If set, any PM files on the node will only be fetched if they 
match this regular expression.(default: $filematch)
-x       : Don't fetch any files. Mark all files on the node as already fetched
           This can be used the first time you run xmlcollect, so that only
           files fetched from this point in time on will be fetched.
-norbs   : Don't attempt to fetch RBS files
-nornc   : Don't attempt to fetch RNC files
-noenb   : Don't attempt to fetch ENB files
-maxrop  : Maximum quantities of ropfile per node
           Ordered from most recent to the oldest
-job     : String job name
-subnet  : eNode-B Subnetwork name regex

_EOF_
        exit;
}
```

[image]

I want to use python achieve the same effect. expect for type many `print`, any other way else? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call print with the required string and set the `file` argument to `sys.stderr`:

```
import sys

usage = """xmlcollect [-h] [-g]  [-d <spooldir>] [-m <pmpath>]  [-f <regex>] [-x] [-norbs] [-nornc] [-noenb] [-maxrop <num>] [-job <name>] [-subnet <subnetwork>]

Fetch XML files from a directory and store the file collection in a zip
file ready for collection.
etc....."""

print(usage, file=sys.stderr)
```